# Angular filter exact match

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Okay so i wasnt quite sure what to call this question.

But i have the following `ng-repeat`:

```
ng-repeat="module in modules |filter:{ module_type_id: selectedItem.id } |filter:search:strict"
```

This is iterating through objects that looks like this:

```
{id: 1, name: 'Hello', module_type_id: 5}
```

Now i have `12` module types so any of these objects have a `module_type_id` between 1 and 12.

When i click one of the categories thereby selecting a type the variable `selectedItem` is set to that value. (which then sorts the list)

This works however there is an odd bug.

if i choose the category that has id `1` then elements with id `1, 10, 11,12`

my guess is that the filter is taking part of the value and therefor only shows results that contains the value. and since `1,10,11,12` all contain the value `1` then these results are shown.

So how can i make sure that it only shows the result that exactly match the value?

Comment: can you please make a fiddle of it. I want to see the whole code, working.

Comment: I think strict is not working properly.

Comment: alternatively you can user 'where'  https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#where

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filter takes another parameter that makes it strict, you're using it for your second part...

```
ng-repeat="module in modules |filter:{ module_type_id: selectedItem.id } : true |filter:search:strict"
```

Comment: But, how are you supposed to fix negation to be strict? '!2' will negate 2, 22, 222, 202, 201, etc.  Setting it to strict negates all records.